# My RelativeLayout does not show latest addView()

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to add a child `RelativeLayout` to a parent `RelativeLayout` programmatically on a `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`. However, after running my application, it does not feature the added child layout via `RelativeLayout.addView()`.

I have created a function for returning the programmatically created `RelativeLayout`.

Here's the respective lengthy code for the function, since the returned `RelativeLayout`'s hierarchy is quite big:

```
private RelativeLayout createCards() {
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (250 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (400 * scale + 0.5f));

        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, (int) (15 * scale + 0.5f), 0);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thought_diary_list_blue);
        relativeLayout.setClickable(true);
        relativeLayout.setFocusable(true);
        relativeLayout.setPadding((int) (8 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (90 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (8 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (80 * scale + 0.5f));
        relativeLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

        RelativeLayout firstRow = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams firstRowLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT);

        firstRowLayoutParams.setMargins((int) (10 * scale + 0.5f), 0, (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f), 0);
        firstRow.setPadding(0, (int) (20 * scale + 0.5f), 0, 0);
        firstRow.setLayoutParams(firstRowLayoutParams);
        firstRow.setId(View.generateViewId());

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (40 * scale + 0.5f), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);

        TextView dateTextView = new TextView(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dateTextViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dateTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.BOLD));
        dateTextView.setText("16");
        dateTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        dateTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fff000"));
        dateTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        dateTextView.setLayoutParams(dateTextViewLayoutParams);

        TextView monthTextView = new TextView(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams monthTextViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        monthTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.NORMAL));
        monthTextView.setText("NOV");
        monthTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        monthTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fff000"));
        monthTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        monthTextView.setLayoutParams(monthTextViewLayoutParams);

        TextView yearTextView = new TextView(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams yearTextViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        yearTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.NORMAL));
        yearTextView.setText("1998");
        yearTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        yearTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fff000"));
        yearTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        yearTextView.setLayoutParams(yearTextViewLayoutParams);

        linearLayout.addView(dateTextView);
        linearLayout.addView(monthTextView);
        linearLayout.addView(yearTextView);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_vertical_threedots);

        firstRow.addView(linearLayout);
        firstRow.addView(imageView);

        relativeLayout.addView(firstRow);

        RelativeLayout secondRow = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondRowLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        secondRowLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, firstRow.getId());
        secondRowLayoutParams.setMargins(0, (int) (20 * scale + 0.5f), 0, 0);
        secondRow.setId(View.generateViewId());
        secondRow.setLayoutParams(secondRowLayoutParams);

        ImageView secondRowImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondRowImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (250 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (150 * scale + 0.5f));
        secondRowImageViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        secondRowImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.td1);
        secondRowImageView.setLayoutParams(secondRowLayoutParams);

        secondRow.addView(secondRowImageView);
        relativeLayout.addView(secondRow);

        RelativeLayout thirdRow = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams thirdRowLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        thirdRowLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, secondRow.getId());
        thirdRowLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        thirdRowLayoutParams.setMargins((int) (10 * scale + 0.5f), 0, (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f), (int) (30 * scale + 0.5f));
        thirdRow.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        thirdRow.setLayoutParams(thirdRowLayoutParams);

        TextView thirdRowTextView = new TextView(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams thirdRowTextViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT);
        thirdRowTextViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        thirdRowTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("avenir", Typeface.BOLD));
        thirdRowTextView.setText("12:00AM");
        thirdRowTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fff000"));
        thirdRowTextView.setLayoutParams(thirdRowTextViewLayoutParams);

        thirdRow.addView(thirdRowTextView);
        relativeLayout.addView(thirdRow);

        return relativeLayout;
    }
```

This function is called on a fragment's `onCreateView` as follows:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diary, container, false);

        RelativeLayout writeDiary = view.findViewById(R.id.writeDiary);
        writeDiary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i=  new Intent(getActivity(),WriteDiary.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }



        });

        ImageView imageView= view.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i=  new Intent(getActivity(),ListThoughts.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        diary_mainLinearLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.diary_mainLinearLayout);

        if (diary_mainLinearLayout != null) {
            diary_mainLinearLayout.addView(createCards());
        }

        return view;
    }
```

I admit, I'm a little bit new at Android programming.

The expected result should be a view like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Adding my XML Layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f2fb"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    tools:context=".modules.diary.DiaryFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="40dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/listIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_list_black_24dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/diary_mainLinearLayout">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                                android:text="My Thoughts"
                                android:textSize="25sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/writeDiary"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="400dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/thought_diary_list"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="90dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="80dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="215dp"
                                android:drawableTop="@drawable/td"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_regular"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="SHARE YOUR THOUGHTS"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />


                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/writeDiary2"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="400dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/thought_diary_list_blue"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp">


                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/firstRow"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingTop="20dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                                        android:text="@string/date"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:textColor="#fff"
                                        android:textSize="22sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_regular"
                                        android:text="@string/month"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:textColor="#fff"
                                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_regular"
                                        android:text="@string/year"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:textColor="#fff"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/icon_vertical_threedots" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/secondRow"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@id/firstRow"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/td1" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@id/secondRow"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                                android:gravity="bottom">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                                    android:text="@string/time"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/writeDiary3"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="400dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/thought_diary_list_yellow"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="90dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="80dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="215dp"
                                android:drawableTop="@drawable/td"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_regular"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="SHARE YOUR THOUGHTS"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />


                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/writeDiary4"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="400dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/thought_diary_list"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="90dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="80dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="215dp"
                                android:drawableTop="@drawable/td"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_regular"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="SHARE YOUR THOUGHTS"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />


                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

            </ScrollView>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/addIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ovalpurple"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_addition" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I've just managed to make it work executing the `addView()` on the `onActivityCreated()` method. Cheers